# How to make code completely stop executing upon exiting tkinter window in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a program that is completely based on tkinter GUI, however it also uses a couple of other modules and non related things. So, when I close the window, the code is still being executed as tkinter isnt the only thing it uses. I have tried to fix it by doing:

```
import sys
def on_closing():
    sys.exit() 
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
```

However, if i try to exit the tkinter window with this code active, the entire program crashes. Is there any other perhaps more efficent solution?

Comment: Please specify what the other modules are

Comment: So you have some code running in a separate thread? Or some code running after your mainloop? That should still be possible to run after a call to `root.quit()` - If your code is executed from within your mainloop, then it will cease to run as soon as you close your mainloop, unless you run it through a separate thread.